# onClick and onBlur events not working properly for draft-js div in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing onClick and onBlur to div but it doesn't work properly. onBlur event doesn't fires everytime. Here i am using react package Draft-js.

```
          <div className="form-group" id="task-comments-frm">
              <div>
                <div  onClick={this.CommentBoxClick.bind(this,'click')} onBlur={this.CommentBoxClick.bind(this,'blur')}>
                  <DraftEditor comment={this.state.newComment} handleCommentChange={this.handleCommentChange.bind(this)} />
                </div>
                <div className="pull-right text-right send-comments">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={(this.state.newComment) ? "" : "disabled"} onClick={this.handleAddComment.bind(this)}>Send</button>
                </div>

              </div>
          </div>
```

This is my function. I am trying to change classes with states.

```
  CommentBoxClick(index){
    if(index == 'click'){
      this.setState({ addCommentBox : 'task-comments animated', CommentBoxHeight : '125px'})
    }else if(index == 'blur'){
        setTimeout(function() { this.setState({addCommentBox :'task-comments', CommentBoxHeight : '40px'}); }.bind(this), 200); 
    }
  }
```